# dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier crash 'could not dequeue a view of kind" UICollectionElementKindCell'

Tags: xcode, collections, deque

I am getting the following crash:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'could not dequeue a view of kind: UICollectionElementKindCell with identifier Cell - must register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard'

I do have the following in my ViewDidLoad:

```
[self.collectionView registerClass:[UICollectionViewCell class] 
        forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
```

And the line that crashes is in the cellForItemAtIndexPath callback:

```
UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView 
    dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
```

I've been searching for hours but cannot find any solution.  I've tried subclassing the UICollectionViewCell but get the same error.

With breakpoints I have determined that the registerClass line is being executed before the dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier callback is executed.

Comment: Put a breakpoint at the `registerClass:forCellWithReuseIdentifier:` line.  When it's hit, print `self.collectionView`.  Is it nil?  If so, you forgot to connect the outlet (if using a nib) or set the property (if using code).  If it's not nil, put a breakpoint at the `dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:forIndexPath:` line.  Print `collectionView` when the breakpoint is hit.  Do you get the same pointer that you got from the first breakpoint?

Comment: @robmayoff Followed your steps, before `dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:forIndexPath` it is has same pointer. But when it hits `dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:forIndexPath` it crashes with the same error.

Answer (score 15):

I had this problem because I was calling registerClass **before** I was instantiating my table view object. Working code :

```
self.tableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
[self.tableView registerClass:[UITableViewCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
[self.view addSubview:self.tableView];
self.tableView.delegate = self;
self.tableView.dataSource = self;
[self.tableView reloadData];
```

Answer (score 4):

Also, don't forget the difference between a cell (register... forCellWithReuseIdentifier) and a supplementary view (register... forSupplementaryViewOfKind).

I was *dequeing* it correctly with the supplementary (header/footer) type, but I accidentally *registered* it as a cell type. Duh.

Comment: This answer seems obvious but it can be hard to pinpoint since you just imagine you wrote the right method. Good answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you happen to experience this, in `UICollectionViewController` or `UITableViewController`, do as what rob mayoff said and make sure that your `Collection View` or `Table View` is hooked up property in your Storyboard.

Another common mistake is in the Storyboard you forgot to give the right `CollectionID` or `CellID`.

Answer (score 0):

Once when I was working on collection view cells, I wrote:

```
static NSString *identifier = @"cell ";
```

Looking carefully, you will see an extra space at the end of the identifier string. After realizing my mistake, I hope this will be helpful to someone.

Reference:

[could not dequeue a view of kind: UICollectionElementKindCell with identifier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23148918/could-not-dequeue-a-view-of-kind-uicollectionelementkindcell-with-identifier)