# could not dequeue a view of kind: UICollectionElementKindCell with identifier

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionviewlayout

I have UICollectionView, but it seems that I set up everything right. But I get the error:

```
'could not dequeue a view of kind: UICollectionElementKindCell with identifier PeopleCellForList  - must register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard'
```

My storybord:

[image]

[image]

[image]

My code is:

```
@interface PeopleCellForList : UICollectionViewCell

@end

@implementation PeopleCellForList

@end


#pragma mark - UICollectionView Datasource

- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)view numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return self.arrayPeople.count;
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView: (UICollectionView *)collectionView {
    return 1;
}

- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)cv cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UICollectionViewCell *cell = [cv dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"PeopleCellForList " forIndexPath:indexPath];
    return cell;
}

#pragma mark - UICollectionViewDelegate
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

}
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didDeselectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

}

#pragma mark – UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout

- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    CGFloat width = 106;
    CGFloat height = width;
    if (indexPath.row % 3 == 2) {
        width = 108;
    }
    return CGSizeMake(width, height);
}

- (UIEdgeInsets)collectionView:
(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout insetForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section {
    return UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0);
}
```

I tried `[self.collectionViewMain registerClass:[PeopleCellForList class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"PeopleCellForList"]` in `viewDidLoad:` (during that I tried to remove and not remove cell from storyboard), but that didn't help.

Comment: You have to call `registerClass:...` method on collection view. Check if your collection is not `nil` when you're invoking the method.

Comment: I checked it's not nil, and I tried to call registerClass, pls see my bottom update

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You have an extra space in `@"PeopleCellForList "`

Comment: I put mine in quotation marks in the class field. .. doh! (Dear apple, please can you include field validation in xcode?- thx. )

Comment: Fun fact: I had the same problem too, and I was following the tutorial at https://www.raywenderlich.com/22324/beginning-uicollectionview-in-ios-6-part-12. And it too have a space in the cell identifier... :-)